# Must remove old adhesive before installing new peel and stick vinyl?

Tags: flooring, kitchens, adhesive, renovation, vinyl

Advice needed!  There are three layers of flooring currently in our kitchen :

1) original linoleum

2) 20 year old vinyl tile (something like peel and stick)

3) 15 year old vinyl peel and stick planks

We are taking up the last two layers, and plan to install new grouted peel and stick vinyl over the original linoleum.
Do we need to remove the adhesive leftover from the second layer of vinyl before installing? Really hoping we don’t !! It’s a family property and we’re trying to give it a face-lift on the cheap.

If we do need to remove the old adhesive, any suggestions as to how?

Comment: The issue you will have is uniformity of level and adhesion to the second layer.  I would remove it with an adhesive remover (comes in a 5 gallon pale at Big Box Hardware), one that will not destroy the linoleum underneath as that probably has asbestos. If you installed Ceramic Tile instead you could just lay the mastic and tile and be done. Probably similar costs especially if you get the tile on clearance or sale. I get it when people have cost pressures I do so I like to provide an FYI based on experience: Doing it right the first time is much cheaper than doing it right the second time.

Comment: Thanks so much! The reason we can’t use ceramic (which I would definitely prefer) is that the floor is distinctly not level. We’ve posts in the basement to hold it up, and we’re jacking it up a little at a time. But it was so bad for so long there is no way to level is without rebuilding the whole floor and subfloor, which is beyond both our budget and skill level. The flexibility if the vinyl makes it our best option.

Comment: If we use an adhesive remover, how do we make sure that doesn’t interfere with applying the new floor?

Comment: After using the adhesive remover, there may or may not be some pre-prep agent to apply after wards [Goof Off Professional is pretty strong ] Goo Gone (agent Orange as I like to call it will leave a residue that you must remove).  I would initially just Mop the floor afterwards. Then I would feel the floor for residue - if I had that I would then return with an alcohol based cleaner (like denatured alcohol or isopropyl alcohol (not RUBBING as it has oils in it) ..